# How can I add a batch of sprites to a list in Unity's inspector?

Tags: unity

I have a C# script with a public property:

```
List<Sprite> someSprites;
```

I would like to add **20** sprites to it, from the inspector window. However, it seems like the only way to do so is to drag one by one. Is there a simpler way to batch fill lists in Unity?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to assign multiple objects:

1. **Editor**: Click on the object you want to assign items to. In the top-right of the inspector window, click on the lock icon. Select the objects you want to assign and drag them into the field. Once done un-click the lock icon.
2. **Code**: Assign it using `someSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Location");` inside `Awake()`.

Comment: A video demonstration of technique 1 is available [here](http://youtu.be/876kjncvnOc?t=37m20s).

Comment: Also worth noting, if you're trying to add your own objects to a list in the inspector, you'll need to make sure they have the [attribute serializable](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html)

Comment: For the first one, if you drag & drop them, they seem to be ordered alphabetically, rather than the order of the dragged objects. Is there a workaround that?

Comment: I only understand technique 1 after I watched the video as Kelly Thomas linked. you should drag into the ListField name, not where you normally dropped.